# Is there reactive form in AngularDart?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

In a official AngularDart guide (https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/forms)
there is a way how to build forms via templates driven way.
I would like to use reactive forms (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html) with AngularDart but I even can't find properly reference on FormGroup class (see a screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: It is Dart. Syntax is correct.

Comment: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.common/FormBuilder-class

Comment: Many thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/angular_forms/angular_forms/FormBuilder-class

Answer (score 2):

Seems added in `AngularDart 5`

[NgFormControl-class](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/angular_forms/angular_forms/NgFormControl-class)

Comment: https://angulardart.dev/api/angular_forms/angular_forms/NgFormControl-class